# Gitosis clone error: Unable to read config file. Permission denied

Tags: gitosis

I tried to clone a gitosis repository and got the error:

ERROR:gitosis.app:Unable to read config file: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/sr
v/gitosis/.gitosis.conf'
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

The permission of gitosis.conf is set to 755. I also checked the folders and make sure that owner is gitosis. I cannot see anything wrong with permission. What could be the reason for this error?

Comment: What are the permissions on the *parent* directories? Maybe on of those parent directory doesn't allow access to the sub-elements (which includes `.gitosis.conf`)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. Yes, the repositories directory is not owned by gitosis. Cloned successfully after updating it.

Comment: Good feedback based on my initial comment. +1

Answer (score 0):

"su - git" to git user and
cat the gitosis.conf file.
if you cannot see the content of the file.
then you need to fix the ownership and permmisson of file or
the path nodes along the path of the file.

Bill Z